# How can I jailbreak and restore an iPhone 3G on Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, iphone, restore, itunes

I'm new to Ubuntu, and I didn't realize how to make it fully friendly with my iPhone 3G. The matter is that I need to restore it to a custom firmware and I can't find Snowbreeze for ubuntu, or any other tool which let me build my custom firmware. And also, how I would load it into my phone without iTunes?

Thanks and sorry for the bad english.

Note: I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with KDE.

Answer (score 1):

The best option will be a virtual machine, I recomend vmware workstation, this is because y full restored a 2g iphone and ipod touch 4g with this machine.

My virtual machine is in windows 7 32bit; I tink the incompatiblility for restore a apple device is because the basic implementation of the restore procedure depend of librarys that is only for itunes

If you have a question about this you can sendme a mail to anubisapopis@me.com

Answer (score 1):

You can try [iDeviceRestore](https://github.com/Chronic-Dev/idevicerestore) which you need to compile, to restore your iPhone, but you still need to make a custom firmware in a virtual machine.